# How to Compare date formated as day with some day?

Tags: excel, formula

In one of the excel cell is the date (say 01.11.2013). I have formated this cell as DDDD so it is displayed as day (for this date it is Friday).

Now I am not able to compare the contents of the cell (actually being displayed as Friday) with string "Friday".

Is it possible? I have used Value(Text) formula and Exact(text, text) formula but it does not helps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use TEXT function to compare. For example:

```
=IF(TEXT(A1,"DDDD")="Friday","Equal","Not")
```

to compare cell A1 with "Friday"

Comment: This function gives error to me ... I have already tried it. I even tried this function with =Text(TODAY(), "DDDD") but its not working

Comment: found a mistake. In Germany it takes ";" as seperator instead of ","

Answer (score 2):

TEXT function varies by region - you need to use the equivalent of "dddd" for your region....or use WEEKDAY function which doesn't vary

=IF(WEEKDAY(A1)=6,"yes","no")

WEEKDAY returns 1 for Sunday through to 7 for Saturday

Comment: Thanks,,,, Although that was not the exact answer, but it helped me find out the problem.